# Eval doesn't work - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I've never used `eval()` before, so I assume that I just got the syntax horribly wrong. What's wrong with the following:

```
var JSONAsString = '{"item1":"one", "item2":"two", "item3":"three"}';
var JSONAsObject = eval(JSONString);
alert(JSONAsObject.item1);
```

Since it doesn't seem to be working - I load the page and nothing happens.

And yes, I know I shouldn't be using eval. I assume that the syntax for `JSON.parse()` is the same as that of eval... right? If it is, if (after fixing the code) I replace eval with JSON.parse, will it still do the same thing?

Comment: `JSONString` vs `JSONAsString`, `JSONAsObject` vs `JSONObject` - your variable names are incorrect. Besides that, after parsing/evaluating it it's a JavaScript object, not JSON (just to be nitpicking ;)), so `JSONObject` doesn't really fit.

Comment: Assuming you have the variable names correct, `eval`ing the string results in a syntax error because the `{...}` are interpreted as *block* and not as object literal.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - that's exactly why it's JSON *as* (an) object.

Comment: In line 3 you did not have the `As` in the variable name ;)

Comment: Oops... But it still doesn't work that way :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `eval` you need to wrap the JSON in `()`:

```
var JSONAsString = '{"item1":"one", "item2":"two", "item3":"three"}';
var JSONAsObject = eval('(' + JSONAsString + ')');
alert(JSONAsObject.item1);
```

However, you should use `JSON.parse()` **right from the beginning**, not just later. Otherwise possibly invalid JSON that is valid JavaScript might work but stop working when switching to `JSON.parse`.

Note that you should include [`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) when using `JSON.*` since some older browser do not have native JSON support.

Comment: Aah, thanks! Does that go for all code that I put into a variable and then parse using `eval()`, or just JSON?

Comment: Use `JSON.parse()` and forget the rest.

Comment: What @MaxArt says. But in any case, if you `eval()` an *expression* you'll want `()` around it to ensure it's not evaluated as a *statement*.

Comment: So yeah, about JSON.parse - does it require similar syntax? So, again, if I went into some code which used eval to parse JSON and replaced it with JSON.parse, without changing anything else, would that still be fine?

Comment: Yes, you simply use `JSON.parse(some_string_containgin_json)`

Comment: That's weird. It all works now that I've imported the script, but you said that older browsers don't support it without the script and it doesn't work without the script in my browser (Chrome 20 beta). Isn't that the newest version?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use eval() to parse JSON. Use Douglas Crockfords json2, which gives you cross-browser support, performance and security: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js